# Should we insert an object into a mongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, object

Can we insert an object into a mongoDB collection ?

For example in **node.js** we want to insert a mathematical formula into a **mongoDB** collection.

Rather than :

```
db.formula.insert({name : 'name', formula : 'R=V1+V2'});
```

should we insert an image as in :

```
db.formula.insert({name : 'name', formula : 'img.pgn'});
```

**How can we store a mathematical formula, an image, an object into a mongoDB collection ?**

In mongoDB would we store the full object or a reference for the object ?

Comment: What is your question? If you can insert an object into mongoDB? If you should use paths to images showing the formula vs represent formulas as strings? The latter is impossible to answer without context.

Comment: What do you want to do with the formula afterwards? Also, are you aware that you aren't storing an image but just a name of an image file?

Comment: We may use the mathematical formula simply as a piece of useful information, not for direct implementation...

Comment: How is it stored in the first place? Is it an image, or a string, or a data structure of some sort? How you should store it depends entirely on what you are storing. "A formula" is very vague... What are your requirements and limitations?

Comment: "R=V1+V2" is an example of a mathematical formula ; we aim at storing any useful piece of information included in a word or email type of document or any enclosed object, into a mongoDB database

Comment: You can store your information in any way you want: image, string, object... Simply pick what is best for you.